# Annotating one dataFrame using another dataFrame, if there is matching value in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames I want to first look for matching values in col1 in dataFrame1 to col1 in DataFrame2 and print out all the columns from DataFrame1 with additional columns from DataFrame2.
For Example

I have tried following ,

```
data    = 'file_1'
Up      = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(data, sep='\t')
Up      = Up.reset_index(drop=False)
Up.head()
    Gene_id baseMean    log2FoldChange  lfcSE   stat    pvalue  padj
0   ENSG.16 176.275036  0.9475260059    0.4310373793    2.1982455617    0.0279316115    0.198658
1   ENSG.10 80.199435   0.4349592748    0.2691551416    1.6160169639    0.1060906455    0.369578
2   ENSG.15 1649.400749 -0.0215428237   0.1285061198    -0.1676404495   0.8668661474    0.947548
3   ENSG.10 25507.767530    0.5145516695    0.2473335499    2.0803957642    0.0374892475    0.229378
4   ENSG.12 70.122885   -0.2612483888   0.2593848667    -1.00718439
```

and the second dataframe is,

```
mydata  = 'file_2'
annon = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(mydata, sep='\t')
annon = annon.reset_index(drop=False)

annon.head()
    Gene_id     sam_1   sam2    sam3    sam4    sam5    sam6    sam7    sam8    sam9    sam10   sam11
0   ENSG.16 404 55  33  39  102 43  193 244 600 174 120
1   ENSG.10 58  89  110 69  64  48  61  81  98  75  119
2   ENSG.15 1536    1246    2540    1751    1850    2137    1460    1362    2158    1367    1320
3   ENSG.10 28508   23073   19982   13821   20355   28835   26875   25632   27131   30991   29351
4   ENSG.12 87  81  121 67  98  47  37  59  68  44  81
```

and following is what i tried so far,

```
x=pd.merge(Up[['Gene_id' , 'log2FoldChange ', 'pvalue ' , 'padj']] , annon , on = 'Gene_id')
```

x.head()
    Gene_id log2FoldChange  pvalue  padj    sam_1   sam2    sam3    sam4    sam5    sam6    sam7    sam8    sam9    sam10   sam11

Its just giving me header of the file and nothing else..
And so I looked into file1(Up) with one row value  like following,
This what i am  getting

```
print(Up.loc[Up['Gene_id'] =='ENSG.16'])

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gene_id, baseMean , log2FoldChange , lfcSE , stat , pvalue , padj]
Index: []
```

But infact that is not empty and it has values in dataframe Up.

Any solutions would be great..!!!

Comment: Won't `Dataframe1.merge(Dataframe2)` just work? You've not stated what the column names are for the first df

Comment: No merge wont work because both of the dataframe are of different length...Also it print outs all the rows without looking for matching ones

Comment: The input files are in the exact same format as I have mentioned in the question and for that kind of data Frame the above solution wont work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.merge(df1[['Gene_Id' , 'log2FoldChange', 'pvalue' , 'padj']] , df2 , left_on='Gene_Id' , right_on= 'Gene_id')
```

[image]

you can then easily drop `Gene_id` if you want

Comment: Sorry now I have added the heading for each file...And the script is not working on the DataFrame... its throwing error as follows, IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Comment: Sorry one more thing , its still throwing error as, KeyError: "['Gene_Id' 'log2FoldChange' 'pvalue'] not in index"

Comment: do you have columns with these names or not

Comment: yes I did it  by  df1.reset_index(drop=False) and df2.reset_index(drop=false)

Comment: if you're using `reset_index` , you've to set `inplace` parameter to be `True`

Comment: Ok, I tried it without other paratmeters, just like this,pd.merge(Up[['Gene_id']] , annon , left_on='Gene_id' , right_on= 'Gene_id') and its printing out the header from df2 and nothing else, means No other rows..Just header , thts what I mean

Comment: sure , you've to include other columns if you want them to show up in the result , I'm sure you don't have columns with these names , try this `Up.columns` , what are the columns in your result

Comment: Index(['Gene_id', 'baseMean ', 'log2FoldChange ', 'lfcSE ', 'stat ', 'pvalue ',
       'padj'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Ok try the same solution Replace df1 with Up , this should work

Comment: pd.merge(Up[['Gene_id','log2FoldChange ','pvalue ','padj']] , annon , left_on='Gene_id' , right_on= 'Gene_id') this what i tried just with changing the names of fiel sfrom df1 to Up and df2 to annon

Comment: Also Merge wont work on this kind of data frame as the both dataframes Up(df) and annon(df2) are of diifferent size , also they are are of different order ..to do a 'merge ' on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95712/discussion-between-user1017373-and-nader-hisham).

Comment: Looks like you didn't copy my answer , actually on Up dataframe the column you want to join on is Gene_Id instead of Gene_id columns are case sensitive , make sure you typed columns correctly

Comment: Yes, I correctly checked  the spelling..In fact the question has a typo and in original data Frame its Gene_id and sorry for that ..Because here i think I need some thing which will iterate over each row and check whether Gene_id from df1(Up) is matching to Gene_id from annon(df2) . And if it is matching then I need it to be printed out as I stated in the initial question... So I think merge is not a right solution is for this issue

Comment: In [73]:

​
x=pd.merge(Up[['Gene_id' , 'log2FoldChange ', 'pvalue ' , 'padj']] , annon , left_on='Gene_id' , right_on= 'Gene_id')
x
Out[73]:
Gene_id log2FoldChange pvalue padj ATCACG_HD TTAGGC_HD TGACCA_HD CAGATC_HD ACTGAT_HD GAGTGG_HD

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

Let me know if it works.

```
import pandas as pd

# creating test Dataframe1
df = pd.DataFrame(['ENSG1',  162.315169869338,    0.920583258294463,   0.260406974056691,   3.53517128959092,    0.000407510906151687,    0.0176112964515702])
df=df.T


# important thing is make column 0 as its index
df.index=df[0]
print(df)

# creating test Dataframe2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['ENSG1',   404, 55,  33,  39,  102, 43, 193, 244, 600, 174, 120])
df2=df2.T

# important thing is make column 0 as its index
df2.index=df2[0]
print(df2)

# concatinate both the frames using axis=1 (outer or inner as per your need)

x = pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1,join='outer')

print(x)
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help, its not printing out the way I have mentioned in the first question...